# How to use rootcert.pem certificate with curl?

Tags: certificate, curl

I have a file/certificate in next format [rootcert.pem](http://webacs.iptv.ch/ca/rootcert.pem). How to use this certificate with curl ?

Comment: On what operating system? How was curl built?

Comment: Standart curl build from ubuntu for example.

Answer (score 10):

You could try to use key `--cacert` or separate this certificate to three different files, put them in one directory and use key `--capath`.

```
curl --cacert ~/cert.pem https://yoursite.tld
```

or

```
curl --capath ~/certdir/ https://yoursite.tld
```